# MySQL - "CREATE_OPTIONS" in "information_schema.tables"?

Tags: mysql, innodb, information-schema

I have a MySQL 5.7.16 Enterprise running on a Centos 6 machine with InnoDB as the default storage engine. I have around 300 tables in which around 90 are "list" partitioned.

I have the option `innodb_stats_on_metadata=0` in my server configuration.

When I query the metadata using the query,

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_sCHEMA = 'mydb';
```

I can see the column **CREATE_OPTIONS** as empty for some non-partitioned columns, **row_format=DYNAMIC** for some non-partitioned tables, **partitioned** for some partitioned tables and **row_format=DYNAMIC partitioned** for some partitioned tables.

Why does this happen when all my tables have the same row format "**Dynamic**"?

I have table collations as "*utf8_general_ci*" for some tables and "*latin1_swedish_ci*" for some tables. Does this have something to do with the above scenario?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that LIST partitioning is beneficial?

Comment: Besides being beneficial, it's required for our domain.

Comment: What do you mean by "required for our domain"??

Comment: We have to maintain data for multiple clients and each client has huge and different data in the same structure. So, list partitioning is the only method we can adopt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for my question. "CREATE_OPTIONS" gets updated as **row_format=DYNAMIC** when you specify it in the create statement explicitly. For partitioned tables, it takes **row_format=DYNAMIC partitioned**.

Table collation has nothing to do with it.